# Partial Derivatives with respect x in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I am completely new to matlab. I would like to know how we could do the partial derivative for the following equation with respect to x

f(t) = 4*sin(a(t)) + x(t)*y(t) + h + cos(y(t))*sin(x(t))

Comment: Hi, please post the code of your tries, especially if you are new in a language.  In stackoverflow it's a best practice not post a problem without posting some tries. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do symbolic derivatives and assuming that `t` is the independent variable, `h` is some constants, and `x`, `y`, and `a` are functions of `t`, you can do:

```
% declare the symbolic variables
syms t h

% define x, y, and a as functions of t
x = @(t)sin(t);
y = @(t)cos(t);
a = @(t)sech(t);

% define f as function of x, y, a, t, and h
f = 4*sin(a(t)) + x(t)*y(t) + h + cos(y(t))*sin(x(t));

%calculate the derivative
df = diff(f,x);
```

If you want *numerical* derivatives then it would be necessary some more information about the data.